# Remove unused keys from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, automation

Hello I'm looking for the best way to automatize my problem:
I am working on a web application in which I use JSON translation files that have this form:

```
{ "unique_key" : "value"}
```

I have several files, one for each supported language, which all have the same number of items.

Ex :

i18n_en.json

```
{ "greeting" : "Hello"}
```

i18n_fr.json

```
{ "greeting" : "Bonjour"}
```

I have very badly managed the evolution of these files, and I end up with keys that are no longer used (I easily think 30% of the ~500 keys), the problem being that I don't know which ones. And that I would have to manually search through the entire architecture of my application to find those that are used and redo a clean file.

My idea to automate this process being:

1. Open one of the JSON files (no matter which one, they all have the
   same number of keys).
2. Loop for each key
3. For each key, browse the entire architecture of my project ( by
   looking only in the *.html or *.js files)
4. If we find an occurrence of this key, create an entry in a new clean
   json with the key + value of it.

I don't really know which language to use that would be optimized for this kind of task, thank you for guiding me!

Comment: Searching your entire project for each key seems like a nightmare. If you know what functions use the keys, you could do the search once for all those functions, and collect all the keys that reference. Then go through the JSON files and remove any keys that aren't in that set.

Comment: Your plan seems good to me. You can start in any general-purpose scripting language you know well, and if you have any problems, then ask a question here (with a [mcve], of course).

Comment: @Barmar I don't know what functions use the keys, I use AngularJS and most of the keys are string in angular directives, so in many many different html templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating my own shell script :

```
path_to_project=path/to/my/project
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'

rm temp.json
rm final.json
touch temp.json
touch final.json

echo "{" >> temp.json

while IFS=, read -r key value
do
    if grep -r -q --include=\*.{js,html} --exclude-dir={node_modules,bower_components} $key $path_to_project; then
        # write in new json
        echo "\"$key\":\"$value\"," >> temp.json
        echo -e "${GREEN} $key was found !"
    else
        echo -e "${RED} $key not found"
    fi
done < data.csv

echo "}" >> temp.json

#remove new lines
cat temp.json | tr -d '\r' >> final.json
```

For this to work, I had to convert my json file to csv (data.csv).
The final json file needs to be reworked a little manually after the script, but really nothing overwhelming.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like [i18next-scanner](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-scanner) will be useful. You are not the first with such a problem.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.